# Find combinations of objects in R

Tags: r, combinations

I have the following example code:

```
library(caTools)
sample1 = rnorm(20)
sample2 = rnorm(30)
sample3 = rnorm(40)
# could be more samples

args = list(sample1, sample2, sample3) # could be more

> combs(c(args), k=2)
     [,1]       [,2]      
[1,] Numeric,20 Numeric,30
[2,] Numeric,20 Numeric,40
[3,] Numeric,30 Numeric,40
```

However, this is not what is desired. I would like to feed `combs` input that should give the same as:

```
> combs(c("sample1","sample2", "sample3"),k=2)
     [,1]      [,2]     
[1,] "sample1" "sample2"
[2,] "sample1" "sample3"
[3,] "sample2" "sample3"
```

and from there I would want to use `get` to extract the vectors for each `sampleX` object by row.

How can I do this without hardcoding "sample1", "sample2", etc. so that I can have as many as samples as are fed to it?

Comment: `combs` being a function from where?

Comment: 'caTools' package. I just find it installed on my system.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520772/in-r-how-to-get-an-objects-name-from-the-object-itself But nevertheless you will need to explicitly list all objects. Maybe the better way will be to combine all samples in a list, create combinations of indices of samples in the list and use them.

Comment: Just as implemented with the indices. Excellent suggestion. I'd mark this as the answer.

Comment: @DrDom You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `library(gtools)`:

```
combinations(3,2,c("sample1","sample2", "sample3"))
```

Result:

```
     [,1]      [,2]     
[1,] "sample1" "sample2"
[2,] "sample1" "sample3"
[3,] "sample2" "sample3"
```

The same result can be obtained if those objects are named elements of a list:

```
tmp <- list(sample1=1:3,sample2=4:6,sample3=7:9)
combinations(3,2,names(tmp))
```

Or, if those objects are all in an environment:

```
tmp <- new.env()
tmp$sample1 <- 1:3
tmp$sample2 <- 4:6
tmp$sample3 <- 7:9
combinations(3,2,objects(tmp))
```

Comment: What I meant was, how can I not put in `c("sample1","sample2", "sample3")` when all of the elements of these vectors refer to an actual object. I want to capture the names of these objects and get the different combinations of them.

Comment: @Kaleb Where are the objects? Can you put them in a list? Or in their own environment?

Comment: @Kaleb Ah, I see. I think my edits suggesting using an environment - which is basically what DrDom just commented to you - is probably the way to go. Then you can use `get("sample1",envir=tmp)`, etc. to retrieve the objects from that environment.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? I use simplified data as an illustrative example.

#### Edit

Thanks to **@GSee** for recommending two improvements in this approach [see comment].

This is not something I'd be keen to do, but we use `ls`  and the `pattern` argument on the names of all objects in your global environment to return the names of those that fit the pattern i.e. all objects which include `"sample"` in the object names - so be careful - and then stick them in a `list` using `mget`.

We then get the combinations of list elements using `combn` and use an anonymous function to combine all elements of list pairs using `expand.grid`. If you want this as a two column `data.frame` you can use `do.call` and `rbind` the returned list together:

```
sample1 <- 1:2
sample2 <- 3:4
sample3 <- 5:6

args <-mget( ls( pattern = "^sample\\d+") , env = .GlobalEnv )

res <- combn( length(args) , 2 , FUN = function(x) expand.grid(args[[x[1]]] , args[[x[2]]]) , simplify = FALSE )

do.call( rbind , res )
   Var1 Var2
1     1    3
2     2    3
3     1    4
4     2    4
5     1    5
6     2    5
7     1    6
8     2    6
9     3    5
10    4    5
11    3    6
12    4    6
```

Comment: `ls` has a `pattern` argument. e.g. `ls(pattern="^sample\\d+")`.  Also, `combn` has a `FUN` argument.

Comment: @GSee thanks, I didn't know/ was being a bit lazy. I have implemented those suggestions. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach

```
# put samples in separate structure, for instance a list
samples <- list(s1=rnorm(20), s2=rnorm(30), s3=rnorm(40))     

cmb <- t(combn(names(samples),m=2))
apply(cmb,1,FUN=function(x) list(samples[[x[[1]]]], samples[[x[[2]]]]))
```

Comment: See comment to Thomas. This also does not address how to capture object references as strings, AND then find the different combinations of these references.