# print list names when iterating lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I have a time series (x,y,z and a) in a list name called dat.list. I would like to apply a function to this list using `lapply`. Is there a way that I can print the element names i.e., x,y,z and a after each iteration is completed in lapply. Below is the reproducible example.

```
## Create Dummy Data

x <- ts(rnorm(40,5), start = c(1961, 1), frequency = 12)
y <- ts(rnorm(50,20), start = c(1971, 1), frequency = 12)
z <- ts(rnorm(50,39), start = c(1981, 1), frequency = 12)
a <- ts(rnorm(50,59), start = c(1991, 1), frequency = 12)

dat.list <- list(x=x,y=y,z=z,a=a)

## forecast using lapply

abc <- function(x) {
  r <- mean(x)
  print(names(x))
  return(r)
}

forl <- lapply(dat.list,abc)
```

Basically, I would like to print the element names x,y,z and a every time the function is executed on these elements. when I run the above code, I get null values printed.

Comment: You may be looking for `deparse(substitue(x))`.  See this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520772/in-r-how-to-get-an-objects-name-from-the-object-itself

Comment: Nope. this is one time when deparse(substitute(.)) is not the answer.

Comment: Closing this as a duplicate, but I think it should stay around (not be deleted) since the question is presented clearly and with a clear title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use some deep digging (which I got from another answer on SO--I'll try to find the link) and do something like this:

```
abc <- function(x) {
  r <- mean(x)
  print(eval.parent(quote(names(X)))[substitute(x)[[3]]])
  return(r)
}

forl <- lapply(dat.list, abc)
# [1] "x"
# [1] "y"
# [1] "z"
# [1] "a"
forl
# $x
# [1] 5.035647
# 
# $y
# [1] 19.78315
# 
# $z
# [1] 39.18325
# 
# $a
# [1] 58.83891
```

---

Our you can just `lapply` across the names of the `list` (similar to what @BondedDust did), like this (but you lose the list names in the output):

```
abc <- function(x, y) {
  r <- mean(y[[x]])
  print(x)
  return(r)
}

lapply(names(dat.list), abc, y = dat.list)
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Only one problem.  You would need to adjust it to work without `lapply`. The capital `X` throws an error `abc(1:5) #Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'X' not found`

Comment: @RichardScriven, given the title ofthe question and the nature ofthe problem, I don't see how it's a problem....

Comment: @AnandaMahto, I installed new R version, and the `print(eval.parent(quote(names(X)))[substitute(x)[[3]]])` no longer works  and throws the following error, `Error in eval.parent(quote(names(X)))[substitute(x)[[3]]] : 
  invalid subscript type 'symbol' `, is there a work around on this?

Comment: I offered one solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30330104/print-list-names-while-iterating-in-lapply-not-working-in-3-2/30330866#30330866), cross-commenting here for reference only.

Answer (score 4):

The item names do not get passed to the second argument from `lapply`, only the values do. So if you wanted to see the names then the calling strategy would need to be different:

```
> abc <- function(nm, x) {
+   r <- mean(x)
+   print(nm)
+   return(r)
+ }
> 
> forl <- mapply(abc, names(dat.list), dat.list)
[1] "x"
[1] "y"
[1] "z"
[1] "a"
```