# print list names while iterating in lapply not working in 3.2

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I'm trying o output the list names every time I run the function thru `lapply`. I posted this [question earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27727590/print-list-names-when-iterating-lapply)  that I posted earlier, and the answer provided by @Ananda Mahto worked fine until I upgraded my `R` to version 3.2.0. It is no longer working and I get the following error message: `Error in eval.parent(quote(names(X)))[substitute(x)[[3]]] : invalid subscript type 'symbol'`

```
x <- ts(rnorm(40,5), start = c(1961, 1), frequency = 12)
y <- ts(rnorm(50,20), start = c(1971, 1), frequency = 12)
z <- ts(rnorm(50,39), start = c(1981, 1), frequency = 12)
a <- ts(rnorm(50,59), start = c(1991, 1), frequency = 12)

dat.list <- list(x=x,y=y,z=z,a=a)

abc <- function(x) {
  r <- mean(x)
  print(eval.parent(quote(names(X)))[substitute(x)[[3]]])
  return(r)
}

forl <- lapply(dat.list, abc)
```

I'm not sure what the issues is, but I checked all the syntax in the new version of `R` nothing has changed. Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm open to any new ideas as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you restructure it a little, you can get the same effect with a simpler appearance:

```
set.seed(42)
## using your dat.list construction code from above
abc <- function(x) { r <- mean(x); return(r); }

forl <- mapply(function(n, x) {
        message(n)
        abc(x)
    }, names(dat.list), dat.list, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
## x
## y
## z
## a

forl
## $x
## [1] 4.960464
## $y
## [1] 20.1141
## $z
## [1] 38.87175
## $a
## [1] 58.89825
```

I'm presuming you wanted the output in a `list` vice a `vector`, ergo `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` to mimic `lapply`. Otherwise, it's a simpler vector.

It's not as generic in that you have to explicitly pass the names as well as the dat, though you can create a sandwich function at the cost of having to reimplement `lapply` functionality.

A personal coding preference I'm using here is the use of `message` over `print`. The rationale is that the user has the option to use `suppressMessages` (outside the `mapply`, assuming it could/would be buried in a function), whereas suppressing the output of a `print` call is a bit more work.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. And your approach is quick compared to te approach outlined in my question. Any idea on why that could be ? Much appreciated.

Comment: If I had to guess, perhaps it's because I'm not processing anything to determine the string to print. But I haven't profiled it, so I don't know for certain. Glad to hear it works for you.