# write.csv error when using function argument as filename [R]

Tags: r, function, csv

I have a number of dataframes which I want to run some tokenising on and save to csv's. I am attempting to put the code that I have been working with in a function and write a csv with the name of the working file.

For this example I have presented a dataframe called subzibo2. When I run the function though I am getting errors at the write csv stage. I have tried concatenating the filename with both paste and sprintf but neither work.

For the `paste()` option I get

> Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :    invalid
>   'description' argument In addition: Warning message: In if (file ==
>   "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file)) { :   the condition
>   has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

for the `sprintf()` option I get

> Error in sprintf("subs/.%d.csv", prodsplit) : unsupported type

Can someone help please? What am I doing wrong? I have left the alt write.csv in the code as a comment for ease. The steps within the function all work when I run them without being wrapped in a function. For info, they take a spreadsheet and tokenise the column ProdNameReduced, and return a dataframe with all the various token phrase options (phrases or parts thereof) with the number of words in each phrase and occurrences within the subzibo2 dataframe.

```
library(tm) 
library(RWeka)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

subzibo2 = data.frame(ProdNameReduced = c("zibo muffin fold over x 100", "zibo muffin fold over x 1", "zibo sandwich 250s x 1", "zibo sandwich x 1s", "zibo 500g clamshell punnet x 1",    "zibo burger fold over x 300", "zibo burger fold over x 1", "zibo 500g clamshell punnet x 500s", "zibo 1kg clamshell punnet x 500s", "zibo 1kg clamshell punnet x 1", "zibo 4 cavity fruit tray x 1","zibo 4 cavity fruit tray x 500", "zibo 2 cavity fruit tray x 1", "zibo 2 cavity fruit tray x 1000"), Code = c("ZIBOZFO6BOX", "ZIBOZFO6", "ZIBOSANDWICH", "ZIBOS/WICHSINGL", "ZIBOCS85", "ZIBOBURGERBOX","ZIBOBURGER", "ZIBOBOX500G", "ZIBOBOX1KG", "ZIBO781KG", "ZIBO4LOOSE", "ZIBO4", "ZIBO2LOOSE", "ZIBO2"))

ProdType = function(prodsplit)
{
    prodsplit$ProdNameReduced = as.character(prodsplit$ProdNameReduced)

max_ngram = max(sapply(strsplit(prodsplit$ProdNameReduced, " "), length))

    BigramTokenizer <- function(x) {RWeka::NGramTokenizer(x, RWeka::Weka_control(min = 1, max = max_ngram))}

    prodsplit_corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(prodsplit$ProdNameReduced))
    tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(prodsplit_corpus, control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer))
    rm(prodsplit_corpus)
    tdm_matrix = as.matrix(tdm)
    rm(tdm)
    tdm_matrix_rowsums = sort(rowSums(tdm_matrix), decreasing = T)
    rm(tdm_matrix)
    tdm_matrix_rowsums_df = as.data.frame(tdm_matrix_rowsums)
    rm(tdm_matrix_rowsums)
    tdm_matrix_rowsums_df$phrases = row.names(tdm_matrix_rowsums_df)
    rownames(tdm_matrix_rowsums_df) = NULL
    tdm_matrix_rowsums_df$phrasecount = vapply(strsplit(tdm_matrix_rowsums_df$phrases, "\\S+"), length, integer(1))

    colnames(tdm_matrix_rowsums_df) = c("occurence","phrases", "phrasecount")
    tdm_matrix_rowsums_df = ddply(tdm_matrix_rowsums_df, .(phrases), colwise(sum))
    tdm_matrix_rowsums_df = arrange(tdm_matrix_rowsums_df, phrases, occurence)
    tdm_matrix_rowsums_df = select(tdm_matrix_rowsums_df, phrasecount, occurence, phrases)
    tdm_matrix_rowsums_df$selector = character(nrow(tdm_matrix_rowsums_df))

    #write.csv(tdm_matrix_rowsums_df, file = paste("subs/", prodsplit, ".csv", sep = ""))
    write.csv(tdm_matrix_rowsums_df, file = sprintf("subs/.%d.csv" , prodsplit))

}

ProdType(subzibo2)
```

Comment: Just as a test, what happens when you set `file` in `write.csv` equal to "test.csv". Does it run as expected?

Comment: Looks like `prodsplit` is the entire data.frame. Both paste and sprintf take a string as an argument. What do you want to name the file?

Comment: Hi, @Aaron. I want the file to be called subzibo2.csv please. My aim is to pass a variety of dataframes to this function and for the csv output to be named after each dataframe I pass into the function please.

Comment: @giraffehere. Hi. Yes, `write.csv(tdm_matrix_rowsums_df, "subs/test.csv")` works.

Comment: See [In R, how to get an object's name after it is sent to a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10520772/210673).

Comment: Try toString, it's worked for me in the past. `write.csv(tdm_matrix_rowsums_df, file = sprintf("subs/.%d.csv", toString(prodsplit)))`

Comment: Thanx @Kernel_Panic but that didnt work. Still throwing an error. Error in sprintf("subs/.%d.csv", toString(prodsplit)) : 
  invalid format '%d'; use format %s for character objects

Comment: I can't get deparse(substitute(prodsplit)) to work @Aaron. It is just returning gobbldygook with backslashes all over the place.

Comment: Hi @Aaron. The answer in the question you point to returns a character string "a", which is the argument in the function. I'm still not getting 'write.csv' to work and when i test with 'print()' I get 13 lines of code with no ref to suzibo2. It starts like ... [1] structure(list(ProdNameReduced = c("zibo muffin fold over x 100",             
 [2] "zibo muffin fold over x 1", "zibo sandwich 250s x 1", "zibo sandwich x 1s",

Comment: Well, you want it to return "subzibo2", which is the argument to your function, right?

Comment: But I do see something that could be the problem; you have to `deparse(substitute(...))` before you do anything to the argument. So as the first line in your function, put `nm <- deparse(substitute(prodsplit))` and then use that `nm` when you make the output filename.

Comment: That did the trick! Many many thanks.