# Get object name after passed to function, and used in for loop, in R

Tags: r, rpostgresql

This question is asked here [In R, how to get an object's name after it is sent to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520772/in-r-how-to-get-an-objects-name-after-it-is-sent-to-a-function)

However, this doesn't work when in a for loop. For example the following method will write multiple dataframes to a postgresql database,

```
write_multiple_to_postgres <- function(list_of_frames) {
for(i in 1:length(list_of_frames)) {
    object_name <- deparse(substitute(list_of_frames[[i]]))
    write_to_postgresql(object_name, list_of_frames[[i]])
    }
}
```

Where the list_of_frames looks like this:

```
my_list <- list(data_frame_susan, data_frame_bobby, data_frame_melissa)
```

....and is called as:

```
write_multiple_to_postgres(my_list)
```

I want the object_name to be passed as a string to the write_to_postgresql method. But instead I get the following outputs for object_name

my_list[[1L]], 
my_list[[2L]], 
my_list[[3L]]

Where what I want is:

data_frame_susan, 
data_frame_bobby, 
data_frame_melissa

How can I use "deparse(substitute) trick" or some other method to get the object name after being passed into a function and used in a for loop?

Comment: https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/732288980549390336

Answer (score 0):

As you define your list `my_list` there is no way to get back df name back. You should use a named list such as `my_list=list(data_frame_susan=data_frame_susan...)` and then have a loop on `names(my_list)`

```
for (df in names(my_list)){
write_to_postgresql(df, my_list[[df]])
}
```

Now the question is how to prepare `my_list` with corresponding names but with what you say we don't know from where it comes from and how those data.frames are populated.