# Dynamically generate columns in r using existing columns of the data set for multiple data sets

Tags: r

I have  data sets named as data2,data3,data4,data7,data11,data12 & data13. For each data set I need to calculate the error_rate_V2/V3/V4...=(V2/V3/V4...actual-V2/V3/V4...predicted)/V2/V3/V4...actual So, for each data set the calculation will change based on the column we are making predictions for.

For eg data2 looks like :

```
V2.actual   predicted   V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V11 V12 V13
639 1294.704556 53817   13  1   5   39316   13  104 104
2767    2724.884429 5131    3   1   5   39311   2   22  22
673 683.8030988 11332   7   2   5   39315   14  140 80
3100    2556.14175  442 8   3   5   39317   1   0   6
3015    2115.371589 8143    3   1   5   39323   1   6   6

V2  V3.predicted    V3.actual   V4  V5  V6  V7  V11 V12 V13
4338    3410.386101 1516    4   1   5   39315   3   18  18
726 2654.803413 442 8   3   5   39317   2   0   12
730 762.412623  12617   16  5   5   39314   2   0   7
755 1653.438693 6722    1   1   5   39322   2   12  12
673 701.7884088 15572   10  3   5   39315   8   0   16
```

and so on for the other data sets:

I can use the following function to address the data sets but unable to calculate the error rates dynamically & separately for each datsets:

```
Error_Rate=lapply(mget(paste0("data",c(2:4,7,11:13))), transform, 
                  Error_Rate= ?
```

Can someone help out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I created a possible solution. Because I don't know if the datasets are provided in the form of dataframes or matrices, I provide solutions for both possibilities.

First the matrix solution:

```
#### Example with Matrix #####

V2 <- c(5,8,6,2,3,9)
V3 <- c(8,8,1,15,48,58)
V4 <- c(7,8,9,4,5,6)

V2.predicted <- c(5.5,6.4,8,9,3,4)
V2.actual <- c(8,8,1,15,48,58)
V3.predicted <- c(4,8,6,55,2,3)
V3.actual <- c(5,8,6,2,3,9)

# cbind as matrix
data2 <- cbind(V2.predicted,V2.actual,V3,V4)
data3 <- cbind(V2,V3.predicted,V3.actual,V4)

str(data2)
str(data3)

fun_calc_error <- function(data,name) {

  library(plyr)

  str(data) # Debugging

  # Tests if name is supplied, if not, it trys to extract the name from the dataframe/matrix
  # (doesn't work in lapply and ldply, as it tries to access list through X[[1]])
  if(missing(name)==TRUE) {
    dataname <- deparse(substitute(data)) # extracts the name of the data object 
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520772/in-r-how-to-get-an-objects-name-after-it-is-sent-to-a-function
  } else {
    dataname <- name 
  }

  cat("dataname: ",dataname,"\n") # Debugging

  # extract the number of the matrix
  df_num <- as.numeric(gsub("data","",dataname)) # extract number of dataframe

  # creates column names
  col_pred <- paste0("V",df_num,".predicted")
  col_act <- paste0("V",df_num,".actual")

  # reduce matrix to the 2 columns predicted and actual
  new_matrix <- data[,c(col_pred,col_act)]

  # split the matrix by row and apply function
  error_rate <- aaply(.data=new_matrix,
                      .margins=1,
                      .fun=function(new_matrix) error_rate = (new_matrix[1]-new_matrix[2])/new_matrix[2]
  )

  # debugging
  cat("\n str Error rate: ","\n")
  str(error_rate)

  return(error_rate)

}

# Test function for one matrix
fun_calc_error(data3)
```

Then the dataframe solution:

```
#### Example with dataframes #####

V2 <- c(5,8,6,2,3,9)
V3 <- c(8,8,1,15,48,58)
V4 <- c(7,8,9,4,5,6)

V2.predicted <- c(5.5,6.4,8,9,3,4)
V2.actual <- c(8,8,1,15,48,58)
V3.predicted <- c(4,8,6,55,2,3)
V3.actual <- c(5,8,6,2,3,9)

# cbind as matrix
data2 <- cbind.data.frame(V2.predicted,V2.actual,V3,V4,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data3 <- cbind.data.frame(V2,V3.predicted,V3.actual,V4,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

str(data2)
str(data3)

fun_calc_error_df <- function(data,name) {

  library(dplyr)

  str(data) # Debugging

  # Tests if name is supplied, if not, it trys to extract the name from the dataframe/matrix
  # (doesn't work in lapply and ldply, as it tries to access list through X[[1]])
  if(missing(name)==TRUE) {
    dataname <- deparse(substitute(data)) # extracts the name of the data object 
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520772/in-r-how-to-get-an-objects-name-after-it-is-sent-to-a-function
  } else {
    dataname <- name 
  }

  cat("dataname: ",dataname,"\n") # Debugging

  df_num <- as.numeric(gsub("data","",dataname)) # extract number of dataframe

  # creates column names
  col_pred <- paste0("V",df_num,".predicted")
  col_act <- paste0("V",df_num,".actual")

  new_df <- select_(data,col_pred,col_act)
  colnames(new_df) <- c("predicted","actual")

  new_df %>%
    mutate(error_rate = (predicted-actual)/actual) %>%
    select(error_rate) -> error_rate

  # debugging
  cat("\n str Error rate: ","\n")
  str(error_rate)

  return(error_rate)

}

# TEST for one dataframe
fun_calc_error_df(data3,"data3")
```

When you use those functions on one dataframe/matrix it works fine, even without providing the name of the dataframe/matrix, because with

```
dataname <- deparse(substitute(data))
```

I can extract it.

If you want to put a list of dataframes in lapply or ldply, to apply the function to a number of dataframes at once, there will be is a problem. ldply addresses a list element with X[[i]] and is not providing the name of the dataframe.

To workaround this issue I used a loop in the following code. Maybe you find a solution for this issue and I hope the code helps.

```
##### Possible solution for more than one dataframe ####

# Create named!!! list of dataframes
df.list <- list(data2=data2,data3=data3)
# Create list of names
nameslist <- names(df.list)

# Create empty dataframe
df_error_rate <- as.data.frame(NULL)

# loop over list elements
i<-1
while(i <= length(df.list)){

  cat(i,"\n") # Debugging

  # put list element in variable as dataframe
  data <- as.data.frame(df.list[[i]],stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  # put name of dataframe from list in variable
  name <- nameslist[i]

  # apply function
  error_rate <- fun_calc_error_df(data,name)

  # create vector with names of dataframe
  dataframe <- rep.int(name,nrow(df.list[[i]]))

  # bind names and values to data frame
  tmp_err_rate <- cbind.data.frame(dataframe,error_rate,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  # bind rows to big data frame 
  df_error_rate <- rbind.data.frame(df_error_rate,tmp_err_rate)

  # count loop up
  i <- i + 1
}
```