# How to get the column name with reference to an object in r

Tags: r, regex, assign

I have multiple csv files for which I want to access second column for every file and do a regex which will remove all strings after ";". this Pattern is same for all the files.
I have referred this
[In R, how to get an object's name after it is sent to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520772/in-r-how-to-get-an-objects-name-after-it-is-sent-to-a-function) 
This is a sample of my file

```
ID  POLL
1   1,2:ksd ksj 
2   3:jj
3   6:ok0j
```

This is what I have tried

```
 setwd("D:/Data/STN")
    temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")

    for(i in 1:length(temp)){
      DF1=read.csv(temp[i])
      col2=colnames(DF1)[2]
      assign(paste(DF1,"$"),col2)
      DF1$col2 = gsub(":.*","",DF1$col2)
```

In temp I have all names of all files, I tried with assign but no output.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the `list` of `data.frame`s and replace the suffix part in the second column using `sub`.

```
lst1 <- lapply(lst, function(x) {x[,2] <- sub(":.*", "", x[,2])
                        x})
```

As noted below, the `data.frame`s are read into a `list`

#### data

```
temp <- list.files(pattern="*.csv") 
lst <- lapply(temp, read.csv, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: gives me an error   "Error: unexpected ';' in "lapply(lst, function(x) {x[,2] <- sub(":.*", "", x[,2];""

Comment: @Deepesh A typo, forgot the `)`. Corrected

Comment: but what is the problem with data frame ,why you used list instead of dataframe. can this be done using dataframe?

Comment: @Deepesh Yes, of course, you can create data.frame objects in the global environment, but it is not necessary and creates lots of objects and at the end, you may again need some loops to write it back.  Instead everything can be done in a `list`