# Get object name in R as string

Tags: r

I have a number of objects I would like to plot in R and save them to my directoy. To assign the name of each graph I need to be able to obtain the name (as String?) of the object to plot.

An example is:

```
setwd("C:/.../mydirectory/")
myname <- myobjectname(myobject) **I want to obtain the string of "myobject"**
png(paste(myname, ".png", sep=""))
myGraphingFunction(myobject)
dev.off()
```

I have tried the:

```
myobjectname <- function(v1){
  deparse(substitute(v1))
}
```

Which does what I want to do and returns the string I want. Nevertheless, when using it in a loop or in the above graph case it is not working.

I have a function with the argument "month" which will be substituted by "january" or "february", etc. E.G. When using the function:

```
myobjectname <- function(month)
```

Within a loop, altough the variable *month* is now *January* (or whatever), the string I get is always "month".

Summarizing:

```
> deparse(substitute(january))
[1] "january"

> month <- january
> deparse(substitute(month))
[1] "month"
```

Any hint on how for the second case to give back "january" ?

Thanks

Comment: Just print the variable `month`? Also, the function `function(month)` doesn't do anything..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In R, how to get an object's name after it is sent to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520772/in-r-how-to-get-an-objects-name-after-it-is-sent-to-a-function)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope I've understood correctly:

```
myfun <- function(month) {
  deparse(match.call()$month)
}

january <- 1

myfun(january)
#[1] "january"
```

Regarding your "Summarizing" example: It's not possible.

I suspect your question is lacking a representative example. You've minimized too much.

Comment: Sorry. It is the first time I use StackOverFlow and that I am learning R so my bad I have not been clear enough. Ill try now

Comment: I will try to simplify it. I have 12 dataframe (one per month with the month name). I want to plot some info of each one and I wrote a function _mygraphfun_. I want the name of the month in the title:

`mygraphfun <- function(Mymonth,...){
  
  ggplot(Mymonth, aes(x = Date)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = amount), color = "red") +
    ggtitle(Mymonth)
   
  }`

My doubt was regardingg how to pass the string name of _Mymonth_ to _ggtitle_. I try to explained in another way and I just made u more confused maybe. Sorry.

Comment: Are your data.frames together in a list (as they should be)? Then you could simply iterate over the list names.

Comment: Hehe, they are not. This seems like the easiest things. 

Anyways I miss a simple function that you ask R the name of a dataframe and it gives it back as string (being able to store in a variable). I guess there must be a reason but as a newby I still dont get it :P


Thanks

Comment: The line `deparse(match.call()$arg)` breaks when processing in parallel! I get a `unable to create dataset` error. It took me forever to figure out what was going wrong, but I finally found it. Any insight as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

In `month <- "january"`, you have "filled" the variable with the name 'month' with the value 'january'. If you `deparse(substitute())` that variable, you get the name of that variable, which is 'month'. If you want the value as a string, just print the variable, as @docendodiscimus suggested in their comment, which will return the value, which already is a string!

```
> month <- "january"
> class(month)
[1] "character"
> month
[1] "january"
```

---

Note:

Your code, `month <- january` (without quotations marks), does not make sense, unless 'january' is a variable:

```
> month <- january
Error: object 'january' not found
```

but:

```
> january <- "whatever"
> month <- january
> month
[1] "whatever"
```