# "subscript out of bounds" error on my custom function

Tags: r, function, lm

I decided to try my hand writing a simple custom function doing a t-test on some `lm()`-produced regression's estimators (for example, H_0: Beta_j = "some constant" vs H_1: Beta_j < "some constant").

This is my first time creating my own code, but I have been working with R for a few months and I think I have a decent understanding of it, so I do not understand why I keep getting a "subscript out of bounds" on running it.

My code:

```
custom_test<-function(data,coeff,alt,alternative=c("two.sided","greater","less"),clevel=.95){
  dof<-data$df.residual
  top<-data$coefficients["coeff"]-alt
  bottom=coef(summary(data))["coeff","Std. Error"]
  stat<-abs(top/bottom)
  if (alternative=="two.sided") {
    tstat<-qt(clevel/2,dof)
    pstat<-2*pt(tstat,dof)
    return(pstat)
  } else if (alternative=="greater") {
      tstat<-qt(clevel/2,dof)
      pstat<-pt(tstat,dof)
      return(pstat)
  } else if (alternative=="less") {
      tstat<-qt(clevel/2,dof)
      pstat<-pt(tstat,dof)
      return(pstat)
  } else {
      return("Error")
  }

}
```

And I try to run this with standard `lm()` results, `hrsemp` being a var., and get the error:

```
custom_test(fit9,hrsemp,0,alternative="less")
Error in coef(summary(data))["coeff", "Std. Error"] : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

But everytime I run the problematic code manually myself, I do get an answer:

```
> coef(fit9)
(Intercept)      hrsemp  log(sales) log(employ) 
12.45837237 -0.02926893 -0.96202698  0.76147045 
> coef(summary(fit9))["hrsemp", "Std. Error"]
[1] 0.02280484
```

Other Stack Exchange questions regarding this error all seem to be subtly different, and I haven't been able to generalize their lessons to my code thus far.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You should make sure you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can also run and test the function. Right now we are unsure what you are actually passing to the function.

Comment: The error says that either "coeff" is not a rowname or "Std. Error" is not a column name in the object you're indexing. Read `?Extract` -- you passed an invalid index, the same as any other SO posters who hit this error.

Comment: I edited my question above. I looked at what you said, but if I type out the problematic portion of my code manually, I don't get a problem, but for some reason in my code it does give me that error. Why could this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191259/frank) is right; you're getting this error for the same reason at base as everyone else who does: You've tried to access an element of an object that doesn't exist. More specifically, in your case, you're trying to access an element in the `"coeff"` row and `"Std. Error"` column of `coef(summary(data))`. This is a problem because there will likely be no coefficient named `"coeff"`. You want to do the following:

```
custom_test<-function(data,coeff,alt,alternative=c("two.sided","greater","less"),clevel=.95){
    dof<-data$df.residual
    top<-data$coefficients[coeff]-alt
    bottom=coef(summary(data))[coeff,"Std. Error"]
    stat<-abs(top/bottom)
    if (alternative=="two.sided") {
        tstat<-qt(clevel/2,dof)
        pstat<-2*pt(tstat,dof)
        return(pstat)
    } else if (alternative=="greater") {
        tstat<-qt(clevel/2,dof)
        pstat<-pt(tstat,dof)
        return(pstat)
    } else if (alternative=="less") {
        tstat<-qt(clevel/2,dof)
        pstat<-pt(tstat,dof)
        return(pstat)
    } else {
        return("Error")
    }

}
```

and pass the variable name as a string:

```
set.seed(42)
hrsemp <- rnorm(10)
Y <- 1 + 5 * hrsemp + rnorm(10)
fit9 <- lm(Y ~ hrsemp)
custom_test(fit9, 'hrsemp', 0, alternative="less")
[1] 0.475
```

(Note you could alternatively feed the function the actual variable object and use `deparse(substitute(coeff))` -- for example, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520772/in-r-how-to-get-an-objects-name-after-it-is-sent-to-a-function)).

However, you may notice this gives you the wrong answer. That's because you've written your function incorrectly. You probably want something more like this:

```
custom_test <- function(data, coeff, alt,
                        alternative = c("two.sided", "greater", "less"),
                        clevel = .95){
    dof <- data$df.residual
    top <- data$coefficients[coeff] - alt
    bottom <- coef(summary(data))[coeff, "Std. Error"]
    stat <- abs(top/bottom)
    if ( alternative == "two.sided" ) {
        return(2 * (1 - pt(stat, dof)))
    } else if ( alternative == "greater" ) {
        return(1 - pt(stat, dof))
    } else if ( alternative == "less" ) {
        return(1 - pt(stat, dof))
    } else {
        stop("Provide a valid alternative hypothesis.", call.=FALSE)
    }
}


custom_test(fit9, 'hrsemp', 0, alternative="less")
      hrsemp 
7.858176e-05 
custom_test(fit9, 'hrsemp', 0, alternative="two.sided")
      hrsemp 
0.0001571635 
coef(summary(fit9))['hrsemp', 'Pr(>|t|)']
[1] 0.0001571635
```

One of many good explanations of why this is the right calculation can be found [here](http://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/~uctpsc0/Teaching/GR03/MRM_HT.pdf).

Comment: I was deep-down suspecting the double-quotes were throwing off how var. names were being input into the code. Thank you so much for clarifying that for me; someone to explain the nuance of the formatting helped me out tremendously. You even correcting my amateurishly written t-test. I will use your code to figure out how I can build the t-test myself. To advancement!

Comment: No problem, glad it was helpful. You'll get better at noticing the little things like that with time. Good luck!