# How can I use an arguement supplied to a user defined function as both an input and a character string?

Tags: r, function

I find I often am comparing two character vectors to see where they don't match up (typically columns in two different data frames). Because I'm doing this often, I want to write a function to make it easier. This is what I've come up with so far:

```
x <- c("A", "B", "C")
y <- c("B", "C", "D", "X")


check_mismatch <- function(vec1, vec2) {
  vec1 <- unique(as.character(vec1))
  vec2 <- unique(as.character(vec2))
  missing_from_1 <- vec2[vec2 %notin% vec1]
  missing_from_2 <- vec1[vec1 %notin% vec2]
  print("Missing from vector 1")
  print(missing_from_1)
  print("Missing from vector 2")
  print(missing_from_2)
}

check_mismatch(x,y)


[1] "Missing from vector 1"
[1] "D" "X"
[1] "Missing from vector 2"
[1] "A"
```

What I would really like is "Missing from x" instead of "Missing from vector 1". I would like the function to output the name of the actual argument that was entered. Another example of how I would like the function to work:

```
check_mismatch(all_polygons_df$Plot, sb_year$Plot)

[1] "Missing from all_polygons_df$Plot"
[1] "KWI-1314B"
[1] "Missing from sb_year$Plot"
character(0)
```

Any suggestions on how I could do this? I'm open to other ways of displaying the output too - perhaps some kind of table. But the output needs to be flexible to different lengths of output.

Comment: This will most likely answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520772/in-r-how-to-get-an-objects-name-after-it-is-sent-to-a-function

Comment: (1) @Jan's comment is spot-on, use `deparse(substitute(vec1))`. (2) Your function prints everything but only *returns* the data from `missing_from_2`, rendering the function mostly useless other than in console side-effect. How about returning `list(missing_from_1, missing_from_2)`. (3) There's a slight difference (to me) between `print`ing your helper message `"Missing from"` and providing the actual data. `print` has a vector-smell to it, you might consider `message` or `cat` for presentation on the console (and then return a value that's meaningful).

Comment: For more information about non standard evaluation, have a look at the metaprogramminc chapter in [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/metaprogramming.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up front, `deparse(substitute(...))` is what you're asking for, and that is what makes your initial question a duplicate.

Some recommendations, however:

1. `print`ing things to the console is a little off (IMO), since it prepends `[1]` to everything you print. Consider `message` (or `cat`). Since many R environments color things based on comments, etc, I have found it useful to prepend `#` before some text to break it out from other portions of the same text.
2. Your function is operating solely in side-effect, printing something to the console and then losing it forever. The function does happen to return a single object (the value of `missing_from_2`, accidentally), but it might be more useful if the function returned the mismatches.

   With that, I offer an alternative:

   ```r
   check_mismatch <- function(vec1, vec2) {
     nm1 <- deparse(substitute(vec1))
     nm2 <- deparse(substitute(vec2))
     vec1 <- unique(as.character(vec1))
     vec2 <- unique(as.character(vec2))
     missing_from_1 <- vec2[!vec2 %in% vec1]
     missing_from_2 <- vec1[!vec1 %in% vec2]
     setNames(list(missing_from_1, missing_from_2), c(nm1, nm2))
   }
   check_mismatch(x, y)
   # $x
   # [1] "D" "X"
   # $y
   # [1] "A"
   ```

   One immediate benefit is that we can look for specific differences in one of the vectors immediately:

   ```r
   mis <- check_mismatch(x, y)
   mis$x
   # [1] "D" "X"
   ```

   However, this uses the names of the variables presented to it. Realize that with non-standard evaluation comes responsibility and consequence. Consider:

   ```r
   mis <- check_mismatch(x, c("A", "B", "E"))
   mis
   # $x
   # [1] "E"
   # $`c("A", "B", "E")`
   # [1] "C"
   ```

   The *name* of the second element is atrocious. Fortunately, if all you care about is what the differences are for the second element, once can still use `[[2]]` to retrieve the `character` vector without issue. (This is mostly aesthetic.)

   ```r
   mis[[2]]
   # [1] "C"
   ```
3. Also, one might want to repeat this for more than two vectors, so generalizing it might be useful (for *"1 or more"*):

   ```r
   check_mismatch_many <- function(...) {
     dots <- list(...)
     if (!length(dots)) {
       out <- list()
     } else {
       nms <- as.character(match.call()[-1])
       out <- lapply(seq_along(dots), function(i) {
         b <- unique(unlist(dots[-i]))
         b[!b %in% dots[[i]]]
       })
       out <- replace(out, sapply(out, is.null), list(dots[[1]][0]))
       names(out) <- nms
     }
     out
   }

   z <- c("Y","Z")
   check_mismatch_many()
   # list()
   check_mismatch_many(x)
   # $x
   # character(0)
   check_mismatch_many(x, y)
   # $x
   # [1] "D" "X"
   # $y
   # [1] "A"
   check_mismatch_many(x, y, z)
   # $x
   # [1] "D" "X" "Y" "Z"
   # $y
   # [1] "A" "Y" "Z"
   # $z
   # [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "X"
   ```
4. And finally, if you want to be a little "personal" with the presentation on the console, you can go overboard and `class` it with an additional `print.myclass` S3 method.

   ```r
   check_mismatch_many <- function(...) {
     dots <- list(...)
     if (!length(dots)) {
       out <- list()
     } else {
       nms <- as.character(match.call()[-1])
       out <- lapply(seq_along(dots), function(i) {
         b <- unique(unlist(dots[-i]))
         b[!b %in% dots[[i]]]
       })
       out <- replace(out, sapply(out, is.null), list(dots[[1]][0]))
       names(out) <- nms
     }
     class(out) <- c("mismatch", "list")
     out
   }
   print.mismatch <- function(x, ...) {
     cat("<Mismatch>\n")
     cat(str(x, give.attr = FALSE, no.list = TRUE))
     invisible(x)
   }
   mis <- check_mismatch_many(x, y)
   mis
   # <Mismatch>
   #  $ x: chr [1:2] "D" "X"
   #  $ y: chr "A"
   ```

   (There are a lot more things you can do in the `print.mismatch` method, obviously. `str` is the major component of it, and it is the swiss-army-knife of depicting structure.)

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed answer! I'm trying to learn more about writing better functions, so it's great to see the different layers of complexity that there could be for such a function.

Comment: Why does the first function use deparse(substitute(...)) and the second function use match.call()?

Comment: Another way to get at it.