# Get the name of the named dataframe when running a function

Tags: r

I have a list of named dataframes and run a function on them as below.

I need to get the name of the dataframe whilst running the function.

In the example below I want to add a column with the name of the dataframe in and have entered `paste0("df_name")` as a placeholder. How can I replace this to get the name of the actual dataframe?

```
library(tidyverse)

df_list<-list()

df_list$iris1<-iris[1:50,]
df_list$iris2<-iris[51:100,]
df_list$iris3<-iris[101:150,]

df_name<-function(df){
    df%>%
    mutate(df_name=paste0("df_name"))
}

map(df_list,df_name)
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520772/in-r-how-to-get-an-objects-name-after-it-is-sent-to-a-function) stackoverflow post?  It looks like `quote(df_name)` is what you're after to return `"df_name"`.

Comment: Or iterate over the _names_ of the list elements rather than the elements themselves...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't mess with complicated computations on expressions, just use `purrr::imap()`:

```
df_name <- function(df,nm){
  df |>
    mutate(nm = nm)
}

imap(df_list,.f = ~df_name(.x,.y))
```

`imap()` maps over the names & elements of a list in tandem, so you have access to both the list element and it's name in the function you're applying. It's just a convenience function around `map2()`.

Comment: Nice.  Note that `imap()` comes from the `purrr` package.